# MVC 5 Scaffolding

Tags: visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I am using the mvc5 database first approach on a project.

The project is huge, 170 tables or so in the database.

I was wondering, is there a way to automate the scaffolding of the "MVC 5 Controller with views, using entity Framework" per model?
I am pointing to my own Templates (Create.cs.t4, Delete.cs.t4, Details.cs.t4, Edit.cs.t4) and will be changing them quite often

Obviously going through each item to create the "new scaffolding" will take me hours so i was wondering if there is a way to automate this process?

Is there a command i can call to create all the controller and view scaffolding for all the models i have?

Answer (score 0):

As of right now, there is no out-of-the-box solution to automating the scaffolding like you can create a data model for the whole db at once. This would be a good enhancement request to put in, though. Roll up your sleeves or hire a couple of interns.